# Changing pointer address - function

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-address

I have problem with pointers.
This is working fine -

```
int main(void){
    char *w;
    w = calloc(20, sizeof(char));
    w = "ab";

    printf("%c",*w);
    w = w + sizeof(char);
    printf("%c",*w);

    return 0;
}
```

but if i use function like:

```
void por(char *t){
    t = t + sizeof(char);
}
```

and

```
int main(void){
    char *w;
    w = calloc(20, sizeof(char));
    w = "ab";
    printf("%c",*w);
    por(w);
    printf("%c",*w);

    return 0;
}
```

then it prints "aa" instead of "ab".
I know its probably pretty stupid question, but i don't know what is going and how to solve that issue.

Comment: This is wrong: `w = "ab";`  You need to use `strcpy`.

Comment: sizeof (char) is per definition always 1. So no need to write it. So incrementing a pointer can be written simply `p++`

Comment: exactly, you actually got a memory leak here because you make w point away to the other place than where it is allocated

Comment: There is also a memory leak because free() isn't called anywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your por function, t will not be changed. You need change it

```
void por(char **t){
 *t = *t + sizeof(char);
}
```

and call it with por(&w)

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved, but can you explain it ? :) &w - passes adress of pointer, yes ? I cant understand what **t meaning. (sory for my english)

Comment: You need to dig a bit deeper about how function call takes place. Basically, you parameter will be copied in a function, so the original one will not be changed after the call. To change it, you need manipulate its address. Here what you want to change is a pointer, so you need pass the parameter as the address of pointer: the pointer of pointer. Now can you accept my answer so that I earn some reputation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static char *por(char *t)
{
    return t + sizeof(char);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *w = "ab";
    printf("%c",*w);
    w = por(w);
    printf("%c",*w);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are incrementing the copy which is local to the function.